# can't accest to subfolders in public from laravel 5.6 error 404 on /css/app.css and every file in the sub folder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

hello i am new on laravel and i am trying to put some css localy but not work, i try every think to i find here but nothing work

```
{{--<link href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">--}}
<link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

i try with these code and not work. still try go to http://localhost:8000/js/app.js but still saying error 404, i don't understand what happend.

i changed the permission for all files and not work too,
this is my public/.htacces

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

i hope to someone help me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your blade file where you are declaring the assets try:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">
```

You can know more: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-asset

Laravel masks the /public route, That's why your home directory is "/" instead of "/public/index.php"

Comment: i try that and not work, maybe is because i am in localhost? external css and js work well

Comment: ok i find the problem, if i use `php artisan serve` i not got problem but went i use the debugger of phpstorm i got the problem, so i will use only the terminal